# How to get the number of children div in css or sass

Tags: javascript, css, sass

Assuming we have a css list as such

```
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="child"></li>
</ul>
```

with the child items being generated based from an iterator. How can you get the number of children within parent in either css or scss.

So I can dynamically modify css attributes like `padding` based on the nth child.

Comment: are you trying to check if this ul has children or not ???

Comment: I don't think you can "get" anything in CSS. You define rules, rules apply. It's only one way.

Comment: @fcalderan I'm looking for the count to count the number of child to dynamically change css-properties like padding withing the child class.

Comment: u can do that with sass functions and loop

Comment: @collision do you mind elaborating a specific example editing your question? What should change under what condition?

Comment: @fcalderan modified the question above.

Comment: The code in your question is not a 'css list'. There is no such thing as a 'css list'.

Answer (score 10):

Neither CSS nor SASS will tell you how many items there are in a list. You'll need JS for that.

However, with SASS you can generate the CSS for as many children as you want automatically:

```
@for $i from 1 through 8 {

    li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        padding-left: $i * 20px
    }
}
```

Change the number 8 to any number you think will have you covered (10? 100? 1000?).

More info: http://clubmate.fi/for-while-and-each-loops-in-sass/

Comment: this iterates from 1 through 8. If I'm to get this. The problem is u don't know the number of children at a point in time. And may be greater or less than 8

Comment: You won't be able to get a number via CSS. You can change the number 8 to something that you consider a safe bet. Otherwise, you'll have to us JS to add an inline padding to each li

Comment: Will you be giving a specific padding to each child, or will there be some sort of pattern in how you assign it?

Answer (score 1):

Use nth child as explained in this article 
https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css

Answer (score 0):

Use direct children selector `>` and add nth pattern for example:

```
 p:nth-child(2) // get every 2nd child
 p:nth-child(3n+0) // elements whose index is a multiple of 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a numbered class-name to the .child elements, say child1, child2, etc... then you can loop over the set in this manner:

```
$maxElements: 100;
@for $i from 1 to $maxElements {
  .child#{$i} {
    //..do something to child element, eg: 
    color: darkorange !important;
  }
}
```

Not the nicest way as you have to set a max, and some processing happens that is empty, but it seems to work.