# Sass: dynamically setting incremental padding for list items

Tags: css, sass

I am working on a list and I wonder if its possible to have:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

And have each subsequent `<li>` child of the parent `<ul>` have more padding than its    preceding sibling, something like:

20px --> 40px ---> 60px

To get something that looks like:

[image]

**Dynamically, not manually. I simplified it to three `<li>`'s (which makes it seem pointless) but I'm trying to figure if this can work for my real scenario with dozens of `<li>` items without having to nest `<ul>`'s.**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/8zs691Lw/ this might help

Comment: Not sure why the duplicate question links to a `LESS` question, this question is better is suited for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807393/how-to-get-the-number-of-children-div-in-css-or-sass

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make style rules using loops with Sass: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for

Although you'll have to guess the upper-bound of how many list items you might have